# Specifying a filename from textbox in Visual Basic 2012

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an application in which the user populates the path and filename of a source file into a textbox by using an OpenFileDialog.  How do I then pass the contents of that textbox to StreamReader to use as an argument for OpenTextFileReader?

Comment: Use `.Text`? What don't you understand?

Comment: Its hard not to figure this out if you start typing and pay attention to the help VS provides.  Or [OpenTextFileReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.opentextfilereader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: When I try to use .Text as an argument for My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader, I'm getting "Error 1 Value of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' cannot be converted to 'String'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It works ok on my pc

```
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be another way

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim sr as StreamReader=IO.File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    'GET sr.ReadToEnd() to anything you want and process
End If
```

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  I'm still not sure *why* it works, but it works:


`fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(txtSource.Text)`